# Do retag-only edits count for "My Dear Watson" hat?

Tags: support, edits, winter-bash-2012

The "My Dear Watson" winter bash hat is rewarded to users who do 5 edits.

**Do "[retag only](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions)" edits count towards the My Dear Watson hat?**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Based on my experiments, apparently the answer is Yes. :)

Comment: I can confirm that as well, I don't have enough rep points for direct editing but received one after doing some re-tagging.